# Emit socket.io message on http get request (in Express.js)

Tags: node.js, socket.io

In my socket.io / express app I'd like to be able to make a GET request to localhost:3000/send and have that emit a message to all open connections however, this code doesn't seem to be working:

```
var LISTENING_PORT = 1234;

var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

//Example users
app.get('/messages', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/messages.html');
});

//Basket Reservation Namespace
var basket_reservation = io
  .on('connection', function(socket){
    socket.on('message', function(message){
      console.log('Received connection from user: ' + message);
      socket.emit('message', 'Connection started.');
    });

    app.get('/send', function(req, res){
      console.log('sending message to all');
      socket.emit('message', 'Message from GET /send');
      res.send('Message sent.');
    });
  });

http.listen(LISTENING_PORT, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:' + LISTENING_PORT);
});
```

Specifically the line socket.emit('message', 'Message from GET /send'); does not work. The lines above and below it do get called.

Here is the client:

```
<script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.2.0.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var socket = io('http://localhost:1234/');
  socket.emit('message', 'hello');
  socket.on('message', function(msg){
    $('#messages').append($('<li>').text(msg));
  });
</script>

<h1>User #1</h1>


<ul id="messages"></ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your code fails to respond to the `/send` route because you are declaring it asynchronously on `io.on('connection')`.

I recommend declaring this outside of the `io.on('connection')` - I have not ran my code - so not sure if it would run:

```
//Basket Reservation Namespace
var basket_reservation = io
  .on('connection', function(socket){
    socket.on('message', function(message){
    console.log('Received connection from user: ' + message);
    socket.emit('message', 'Connection started.');
});

// Helper to send message (it uses closure to keep a reference to the io connetion - which is stored in basket_reservation in your code)
var sendMessage = function (msg) {
  if (basket_reservation && basket_reservation.connected) {
    console.log('sending message to all');
    basket_reservation.emit('message', 'Message from GET /send');
  }
};

// Broadcast message
app.get('/send', function(req, res){
  sendMessage(req.body.data);
  res.send('Message sent.');
});
```